# How can I fill in the gap between my chain-link fence and its gate

Tags: fence, gates

We have a couple of gates in our chain-link fence and bunnies and large rodents like to squeeze through them.  I would like to fill the gap somehow so the gates are still usable and look halfway decent. Here are a couple of pics of the gate. The gaps are about 5 inches wide.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Remember that the rabbits are just going to go under, and they don't need much of a gap to squeeze through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: My solution]I realize this question is old but perhaps my answer can help someone else who comes across this post while searching for a solution as I did.

What I ended up doing was the following:

1. Get some ‘1 3/8” panel clamps’. I bought mine from Home Depot. These are also called “kennel clamps”. They will hold two 1 3/8” pieces of tubing parallel to each other. You will need one clamp for the top and one for the bottom.
2. Get some ‘1 3/8” post caps’. I got mine off Amazon, since Home Depot didn’t have any. You will need one cap each for the top and bottom of the tubing you will use to fill the gap. This will keep water and nesting wasps, etc., out of the tubing.
3. Get some 1 3/8” chain link fencing “top rail”. In my case I had some left over from a prior project.
4. Measure the length of the gap beneath the gate latch to the bottom of the gate. Be sure to leave a reasonable amount of space beneath the latch so there is room for the post caps and things don’t end up looking like they are crowded together.
5. Cut a length of the top rail according to your measurement. I used an abrasive cut-off saw because I have one, but a hacksaw or even a Dremel tool with cutting wheel and patience will do. Put one of the post caps on either end of the tubing.
6. Fasten the length of tubing to the side of the gate using the panel clamps, suspended between the gate and the terminal post beneath the latch.

Once assembled, the new filler post will move with the gate. It even looks professional.

In my case, my fencing is black powder-coated. None of the materials I was able to purchase quickly were black, so I spray painted everything with two heavy coats of black gloss paint before assembly. It looks good.

This was done in my case to prevent my wife’s rather devious Scotty dog puppy from getting out through the gap.

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen, especially if you care how it looks.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about how it looks, a piece of plywood or other rigid material mounted to the gate would bridge the gap.  You could attach it to the vertical part of the gate using a variety of types of u-bolts/brackets.

Otherwise the easiest thing is to replace the gate with a wider one. Another alternative is to move the posts to reduce the gap on the existing gate but this requires installing posts and replacing the section of fence.

Comment: I am not sure plywood would pass the looks test, but some other type of material might. How would you fasten it to the gate?

Comment: @OffTheGold I've updated the answer

Answer (score 5):

Use a chainlink "terminal post" the appropriate diameter and length and attach it to the existing posts using a zip-tie or ideally a chainlink "brace band."  I got the idea from watching this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GulJ53J-nYs

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but i doubt i would be able to close and latch the gate then.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem at my house and my dog always got out of that gap in my chain link fence. What I did to solve the problem was put in a little bit of chicken wire. It doesn't look that great either, but I thought it looked better than a piece of plywood. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For top picture:

The cheap solution is to buy a new cross bar for the left side of the gate. Buy one size longer than what you have. Cut to size. Splice the existing cross wood by one picket and extend the chain-link accordingly. In theory, you can reuse the bolts and ties. The ordeal is a pain but not that hard or expensive. I'd say less than a day and less than $100 if you DIY.

Answer (score 2):

Get some  white, coated wire shelving pieces. Cut them to size and length of  the  gap.

Install it vertically on the Gate so that  when you close the gate the "extension" from gate will cover the gap. **I.E.** On the gate, on the inside, so it will allow gate to close/open normally, but the added shelf material covers gap.

I used wire and zip ties to secure the wire shelf to the gate.  It worked for me and it's almost rust/insect/water proof.  Good Luck.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Are those coated wire shelving pieces rust proof?

Answer (score 0):

All but the largest rodents will get through the chain link itself, bunnies & squirrels included - It's a loosing battle.